# Signtool: authentication at the timestamp server?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, code-signing, sign

I want to use the timestamp option `/t` resp. `/tr` of the Microsoft Visual Studio [signtool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8s9b9yaz%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) tool. The timestamp service I have in mind requires authentication. For this purpose you get a personalized soft token to identify yourself at the timestamp server.

My question: Is this authentication supported by signtool? In other words: does signtool support RFC 3161 (Time-Stamp Protocol) *and* RFC 2246 (Authentication)?

Thank you

Comment: How is the token passed to the timestamp service? As a request header or as a query parameter?